# Match elements of lists by partly similar strings| Python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've got two lists that contain filenames from different directories.

The goal is to sync the filenames from the target directory to the filenames in the source directory. Since the filenames contain partly the same string, it should be possible to reference them.

---

Directory 1: "random-original.ext" | Directory 2: "original.ext"

Sync with skript:

Directory 1: "random-original.ext" | Directory 2: "random-original.ext"

---

The "S03-ST02..." in here is just an example of random strings. The only thing that will be the same in both files is the the last part before and including the file-extension. The filenames below are just examples -  it should work with all kind of names afterwards.

Input:

```
sourceFiles  = [S03-ST02-T04-VID004.mov, S01-ST01-T01-AV0203.abc, S05-ST02-T01-MOV0014.mp4]
targetFiles  = [AV0203.abc, MOV0014.mp4, VID0004.mov]
```

**Output Var 1**

```
sourceFiles = [S01-ST01-T01-AV0203.abc, S05-ST02-T01-MOV0014.mp4, S03-ST02-T04-VID0004.mov]
targetFiles  = [AV0203.abc, MOV0014.mp4, VID0004.mov]
```

So I can reference the same file (with different names) for example with a for loop:

```
for i in len(sourceFiles):
   sourceFiles[i]
   targetFiles[i]
```

**Output Var 2**

```
combFileList = [(S01-ST01-T01-AV0203.abc, AV0203.abc), (S05-ST02-T01-MOV0014.mp4, MOV0014.mp4), (S03-ST02-T04-VID0004.mov, VID0004.mov)]
```

And reference the same file for example like this:

```
for i in len(combFileList):
   combFileList[i][0]
   combFileList[i][1]
   ...
```

How would I approach this?

Comment: You can iterate over the second list of files and for each of them find the filename in the second list that ends with the first file's name (`sourceFile.endswith(targetFile)`).

Comment: note that you have a typo; on `sourceFiles`  you have `'S03-ST02-T04-VID004.mov'` while on `targetFiles` `'VID0004.mov'` (one more `'0'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `next` here inside a list-comprehension

```
sourceFiles  = ['S03-ST02-T04-VID0004.mov', 'S01-ST01-T01-AV0203.abc', 'S05-ST02-T01-MOV0014.mp4']
targetFiles  = ['AV0203.abc', 'MOV0014.mp4', 'VID0004.mov']

res = [next((x for x in targetFiles if y.endswith(x)), 'N/A') for y in sourceFiles]
```

which produces

```
print(res)  # -> ['VID0004.mov', 'AV0203.abc', 'MOV0014.mp4']
```

Comment: After a short test I think this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
for targetFile in targetFiles:
    for sourceFile in sourceFiles:
        if sourceFile.endswith(targetFile):
            do_something(sourceFile, targetFile)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This would be great for verifying if files match - however I think Ev. Kounis answer is easier to work with.